# dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler: is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm using `AFNetworking` in my project to get the data from REST api.
But when I'm using the method which described in Github I'm getting warning.

**Here is my code :**

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://httpbin.org/get"];
NSURLRequest *request123 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request123 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

My project supports iOS 7.0 and above.

My Xcode version 7.3.1

Is there any way to overcome this warning?

Comment: Can you please post your warning here?

Comment: : 'dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:' is deprecated

Comment: @vadian Agree. Its working on my side.

Comment: Working on my side too! which Xcode and Swift version are you using?

Comment: I am using Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: @himanth Which version of afnetworking are you using?

Comment: @EktaMakadiya I am using Xcode Version 7.3.1

Comment: @himanth not xcode. Afnetworking 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: @EktaMakadiya using 3.0 version of AFNetworking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method belongs to `AFURLSessionManager`. The actual signature (using two blocks) is

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                                      success:(void ( ^ ) ( NSURLResponse *response , id responseObject ))success 
                                      failure:(void ( ^ ) ( NSError *error ))failure
```

Comment: it's available in 2.0  or 3.0

Comment: This is not available in 3.0.

Answer (score 13):

It has now been replaced with the following in AFNetworking 3.0

```
    - (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                           uploadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress))uploadProgressBlock
                         downloadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress *downloadProgress))downloadProgressBlock
                        completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id _Nullable responseObject,  NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

Comment: Its crashing -[AFURLSessionManager dataTaskWithRequest:uploadProgress:downloadProgress:completionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281c275a0